# C# WatiN - Add an AlertDialogHandler to click ok button on every Alert dialog window

Tags: c#, watin

**Hello**

Those who have used [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net) likely also used `DialogHandlers`.

Well can someone teach me how can i assign a `DialogHandler` that will handle any Alert Box *`window.alert()`*, of a specific IE instance under WatiN control .

The DialogHandler only has to click in the OK button for very alert dialog box, in that case i think we need an `AlertDialogHandler` that basically only has to click the OK button.

```
AlertDialogHandler.OKButton.Click()
```

I've search the web and found a few examples.. But they work for a small period of time or the time you specify, i need one that will work forever, until i choose to stop it by clicking a button.

This as been bugging my head for hours, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Note:** Sometimes the alert dialog window has two buttons. Thats why i really need to click the OK button, not just Close the dialog window.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create class:

```
public class OKDialogHandler : BaseDialogHandler
{
    public override bool HandleDialog(Window window)
    {
        var button = GetOKButton(window);
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanHandleDialog(Window window)
    {
        return GetOKButton(window) != null;
    }

    private WinButton GetOKButton(Window window)
    {
        var windowButton = new WindowsEnumerator().GetChildWindows(window.Hwnd, w => w.ClassName == "Button" && new WinButton(w.Hwnd).Title == "OK").FirstOrDefault();
        if (windowButton == null)
            return null;
        else
            return new WinButton(windowButton.Hwnd);
    }
}
```

After creating instance of `IE`, attach dialog handler to it:

```
ie.AddDialogHandler(new OKDialogHandler());
```

This dialog handler will handle all windows, that contains a button with "OK" caption, by clicking on that button.

Comment: @prostynick -may I know what class WindowsEnumerator belongs too?  It appears to be the crux of of your class OKDialogHandler.-  Doh!  I found it in BaseDialogHandler.  Thanks!

Comment: No, I was wrong.  I didn't find WindowsEnumerator in BaseDialogHandler, but rather in WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.