# Watin DialogHandler closes SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, watin, savefiledialog

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454422/c-sharp-watin-add-an-alertdialoghandler-to-click-ok-button-on-every-alert-dial) I have created a custom `DialogHandler` to handle Javascript alert boxes that popup from within a WebBrowser control.

The `Handler` is attached to an inherited WatiN `IE` browser, called `ExtendedIeBrowser`.

For an unknown reason watin's DialogHandler interferes with Winforms SaveFiledialogs. The `SaveFileDialog` is automatically closed by returning DialogResult.Cancel. The strange thing is that the `Handle()` of the custom Handler is never called. Only `CanHandle()` is called (twice) and it returns false, so the dialog is not supposed to be handled at all, therefore it should stay open.

Is there anything that I can do to change overcome this strange behavior?

This is the `ExtendedIeBrowser` source:

```cs
public class ExtendedIeBrowser : IE
{
    private IntPtr hwnd;
    public ExtendedIeBrowser(WebBrowser webBrowserControl) : base(webBrowserControl.ActiveXInstance, false)
    {
    }

    public void Initialize(WebBrowser webBrowserControl)
    {
        hwnd = webBrowserControl.FindForm().Handle;
        StartDialogWatcher();
    }

    public override IntPtr hWnd { get { return hwnd; } }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Following the `CustomPopupDialogHandler` source:

```
class CustomPopupDialogHandler : ReturnDialogHandler
{
    protected static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public override bool HandleDialog(Window window)
    {
        bool handled = false;
        try
        {
            var button = GetWantedButton(window);
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click();
        }
            handled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException("HandleDialog", ex);
        }
        return handled;
    }

    public override bool CanHandleDialog(Window window)
    {
        bool canHandle = false;
        try
        {
        canHandle = GetWantedButton(window) != null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException("CanHandleDialog", ex);
        }
        return canHandle;
    }

    private WinButton GetWantedButton(Window window)
    {
        WinButton button = null;
        try
        {
            if (window.Title.Contains("Windows Internet Explorer") || window.Title.Contains("Message from webpage"))
            {
                var windowButton = new WindowsEnumerator().GetChildWindows(window.Hwnd, w => w.ClassName == "Button" && (new WinButton(w.Hwnd).Title.Contains("Leave") || new WinButton(w.Hwnd).Title.Contains("OK")).FirstOrDefault();
                if (windowButton != null)
                {
                    string s = windowButton.Title;
                    button = new WinButton(windowButton.Hwnd);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException("GetWantedButton", ex);
        }
        return button;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know watin can interfere with dialogs other than `WebBrowser`'s !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WatiN.Core.Settings.AutoCloseDialogs = false;
```

By default is set to `true`.